# What do I have to do to be able to use SQLite annotations in a Windows Store app?

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps, data-annotations

What need I do besides reference  SQLite for Windows Runtime (Windows 8.1) to be able to annotate class members such as:

```
public class PlatypusData
{
        [SQLite.PrimaryKey]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public double poisonToeLengthInCentimeters { get; set; }
        . . . // even King Kong exposed his API
}
```

As mentioned, I've got the SQLite reference in my project; right-clicking the "SQLite.PrimaryKey" annotation/decoration affords no "Resolve" context menu item.

What am I missing?

Comment: did you add [sqlite-net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net) to your project?

Comment: No; that must be my problem. I'll add that; if it solves it, you can make it an answer.

Comment: ..yeah, that was it - make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have added to the project is the SQLite database engine. It provides a low level C API to do db access. It does not contain the `PrimaryKey` attribute that you are looking for.

To add that specific attribute, you will need the [sqlite-net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net) library. Sqlite-net calls (abstracts) the low level C API so that you do not have to; it provides a higher level .Net friendly API for accessing the db.